# Show that $int \gamma=\{z \notin \gamma^+/ \eta(\gamma,z)\neq0\}$ is closed and bounded

Tags: functional-analysis

Show that $int \gamma=\{z \notin \gamma^+/ \eta(\gamma,z)\neq0\}$ is closed and bounded

Here $\gamma:[a,b]\to \mathbb{C}$ is a $C^1$ curve, $\gamma^*$ represents image of $\gamma$ and $\eta(\gamma, z)$ is the winding number

can you some tell me how to prove this i am sorry i am not attempt anything because  i have no idea about this

Answer (score 0):

Since $n(\gamma ,z)$ is a continuous integer valued function the given set is $\{z\notin \gamma ^{+}: |n(\gamma ,z)| \geq 1\}$ which is closed because it is inverse image of a closed set under a continuous function.